# Using a FormArray instead of FormControl Angular

Tags: html, angular

I would like to use FormArray instead of FormControl for the following typescript code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { WebsocketService } from '../../core/websocket.service';
import { AppEngineMessage } from '../../core/models/app-engine-message';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-auxilary',
  templateUrl: './auxilary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auxilary.component.css']
})
export class AuxilaryComponent implements OnInit {

  private appEngineMsg: AppEngineMessage;
  public auxConfigform: FormGroup;
  @Input() m_bReadOnly: boolean;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private wsService: WebsocketService) { }

  // ---------INTIALISING VALUES BASED ON VALUES FROM WEBSOCKET-------------------------------
  ngOnInit() {
    // ------------------------FORM CONTROL IS DECLARED FOR DESCRIPTION-------------------
    // this.auxConfigform = this.fb.group({
    //   desc : this.fb.array([8]),
    //   temp : this.fb.array([4]),
    //   switch : this.fb.array([4]),
    //   space : this.fb.array([4])
    // });

    this.auxConfigform = new FormGroup({
      desc0: new FormControl(),
      desc1: new FormControl(),
      desc2: new FormControl(),
      desc3: new FormControl(),
      desc4: new FormControl(),
      desc5: new FormControl(),
      desc6: new FormControl(),
      desc7: new FormControl(),

      //-------------------------FORM CONTROL IS DECLARED FOR TEMPSENSOR--------------------
      temp0: new FormControl(),
      temp1: new FormControl(),
      temp2: new FormControl(),
      temp3: new FormControl(),
      //-------------------------FORM CONTROL IS DECLARED FOR Switch radio button--------------------
      switch4: new FormControl(), 
      switch5: new FormControl(),
      switch6: new FormControl(),
      switch7: new FormControl(),
      //-----------------------FORMCONTROL IS DECLARED FOR SPACE SENSOR Radio button--------------------
      space0: new FormControl(),
      space1: new FormControl(),
      space2: new FormControl(),
      space3: new FormControl(),
    });

    this.wsService.appEngineMsg.subscribe(appMsg => {
      if (Object.keys(appMsg).length != 0) {
        this.appEngineMsg = appMsg;

        //-----------This is used to intialise Decription text Box-----------------------------------
        for (let i=0; i<8; i++)
          this.auxConfigform.controls['desc'+i].patchValue(this.appEngineMsg.AUX[i].Description);
        for (let i=0; i<4; i++)
          this.auxConfigform.controls['temp'+i].patchValue(String(this.appEngineMsg.AUX[i].TempSensor));
        for (let i=4; i<8; i++)
          this.auxConfigform.controls['switch'+i].patchValue(String(this.appEngineMsg.AUX[i].TempSensor));
        for (let i=0; i<4; i++)
          this.auxConfigform.controls['space'+i].patchValue(this.appEngineMsg.AUX[i].SpaceAvg);
      }
      else {
        for (let i=0; i<4; i++)
          this.auxConfigform.controls['temp'+i].patchValue('false');
        for (let i=4; i<8; i++)
          this.auxConfigform.controls['switch'+i].patchValue('false');
        }
    });
    if (this.m_bReadOnly)
      this.auxConfigform.disable();
  }
}
```

but I do not know the correct syntax for object indexing in the template URL

```
<form [formGroup]="auxConfigform" (ngSubmit)="onFinish()">
  <div>
    <label for="" class="w60">AUX 1</label>
    <input matInput matKeyboard type="text" name="desc0" placeholder="" class="txt-fld-200" formControlName="desc0"
      maxlength="50">

    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="temp0" value='false' formControlName="temp0">
    <label for="test2" class="w140">Switch</label>
    <input type="radio" id="test1" name="temp0" value='true' formControlName="temp0">
    <label for="test1" class="pr-40" *ngIf="m_bReadOnly==false">Temp Sensor</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="radio-group1" formControlName="space0"
      *ngIf="m_bReadOnly==false && auxConfigform.get('temp0').value=='true'">
    <label for="check" *ngIf="m_bReadOnly==false && auxConfigform.get('temp0').value=='true'">Space Sensor </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="" class="w60">AUX 2</label>
    <input matInput matKeyboard type="text" name="desc1" placeholder="" class="txt-fld-200" formControlName="desc1"
      maxlength="50">
    <input type="radio" id="test5" name="temp1" value='false' formControlName="temp1">
    <label for="test5" class="w140">Switch</label>
    <input type="radio" id="test4" name="temp1" value='true' formControlName="temp1">
    <label for="test4" class="pr-40" *ngIf="m_bReadOnly==false">Temp Sensor</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="radio-group2" class="checkstyle" formControlName="space1"
      *ngIf="m_bReadOnly==false && auxConfigform.get('temp1').value=='true'">
    <label for="check2" *ngIf="m_bReadOnly==false && auxConfigform.get('temp1').value=='true'">Space Sensor </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have the other question, how to automatic generate my GUI base on the JSON array in ngOnInit function? For example, my this.appEngineMsg.AUX is as below:

```
 [{
        "Description": "",
        "TempSensor": true,
        "SpaceAvg": false,
        "SwitchStatus": false
    },
    {
        "Description": "",
        "TempSensor": true,
        "SpaceAvg": false,
        "SwitchStatus": false
    },
    {
        "Description": "",
        "TempSensor": true,
        "SpaceAvg": false,
        "SwitchStatus": false
    },
    {
        "Description": "",
        "TempSensor": true,
        "SpaceAvg": false,
        "SwitchStatus": false
    },
    {
        "Description": "",
        "TempSensor": true,
        "SpaceAvg": false,
        "SwitchStatus": false
    },
    {
        "Description": "",
        "TempSensor": true,
        "SpaceAvg": false,
        "SwitchStatus": false
    },
    {
        "Description": "",
        "TempSensor": true,
        "SpaceAvg": false,
        "SwitchStatus": false
    },
    {
        "Description": "",
        "TempSensor": true,
        "SpaceAvg": false,
        "SwitchStatus": false
    }
]
```

[image]

If I add or remove an element in JSON array, the GUI will be updated correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

Since you have array of Object, create FormGroup with individual form control property then use [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#validators)  to add Validation to reactiveform instead of adding html attribute on template.

**component.ts**

```
 const arryOfAuxGroup = this.AUX.map(item => {
      return this.createauxGroup(
        item.Description,
        item.TempSensor,
        item.SpaceAvg,
        item.SwitchStatus
      );
    });
this.auxConfigform = this.fb.group({
      aux: this.fb.array(arryOfAuxGroup)
});
createauxGroup(description, tempSensor, spaceAvg, switchStatus) {
    return this.fb.group({
      description: [description, Validators.maxLength(50)],
      tempSensor: [tempSensor],
      spaceAvg: [spaceAvg],
      switchStatus: [switchStatus]
    });
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-example-1)